# Cancelled orders stock is not returning

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.2.3

Whenever an order is placed, stock is being deducted as it should. However when the order is cancelled the stock isn't being returned to the total available qty. This happens for both simple products and configurable products.

The options I have **Catalog -> Inventory -> 
Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled -> Yes** but it has no affect when an order is cancelled if it's out of stock it still stays out of stock.

Is this something that the cron job is meant to take care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was a plugin that was recently installed - Codisto ebay integration. Completely removing the plugin fixed the issue.

It produced a few issues one of which was the one posted above.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue Resolved

This issue has been resolved. See https://github.com/CodistoConnect/CodistoConnect/commit/b028c3fd9d28b64478d8d7ff3a4e3b02996fbbdb#diff-de8072aa6ebf3f1197e1c3a5d0715ee1L155.

## Root Cause

We were observing sales_order_item_cancel events, we have turned this off as we already pick up such stock movements via the indexer architecture.

Comment: Awesome that's good to know. Thanks for the heads up. Kudos for checking Magento SE too!